# SPFx - Get list items from different site collection where user have access

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp, react, sharepoint-framework

Link-1: https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/site-1/
Link-2: https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/site-2/

Using SPFx, From Link-1 site webpart, I want to get list items from Link-2 site.

I tries axios, fetch and pnp it works well in workbench but while deploy webpart at that time it throws Unauthorized exception.

Please share advise here.

Comment: did you use the https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-http/sphttpclient?view=sp-typescript-latest client in order to initiate the request?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following test that shows a web part hosted in one site can access list items from another site as long as the current user has access to both sites.

This sample uses the `SPHttpClient` type to get data from the Categories list in the Demo site.

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

//...

protected get isRenderAsync(): boolean {
  return true;
}

public async render(): Promise<void> {
  const response: SPHttpClientResponse = await this.context.spHttpClient.get(
    "https://robwindsortest991.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Categories')/Items",
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1
  );

  if (response.ok == false) {
    const responseError: string = await response.text();
    this.context.statusRenderer.renderError(this.domElement, responseError);  
    this.renderCompleted();
    return;
  }

  const jsonResponse: any = await response.json();

  let categoryItems: string = "";
  jsonResponse.value.forEach((category: any) => {
    categoryItems += "<li>" + category.Title + "</li>";
  });

  this.domElement.innerHTML = `
  <section class="${styles.helloWorld} ${!!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams ? styles.teams : ''}">
    <div class="${styles.welcome}">
      <img alt="" src="${this._isDarkTheme ? require('./assets/welcome-dark.png') : require('./assets/welcome-light.png')}" class="${styles.welcomeImage}" />
      <h2>Well done, ${escape(this.context.pageContext.user.displayName)}!</h2>
      <div>${this._environmentMessage}</div>
      <div>Web part property value: <strong>${escape(this.properties.description)}</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Categories</h3>
      <ul>
        ${categoryItems}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>`;

  this.renderCompleted();
}
```

If I package an deploy this web part and then add it to a page in the Demo2 site, users who have permissions to access both sites see the list data.

[image]

However, users who have permissions to access to the Demo2 site, but who don't have permissions to access to the Demo site, get an error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Rob for your quick reply!

I used your code but getting 403 (Unauthorized access) response code. Even user has full access on site. 

Please advise here.

Comment: What happens when the user navigates to the list containing the data in SharePoint?

Comment: I am trying to access Site Pages library. 

Link: https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/Templates/_api/lists/getByTitle('Site%20Pages')/items

Above link is accessing in browser but with your code it throws 403 error.

Comment: The REST API URL to access the Site Pages library should end with /_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Site%20Pages')/Items. The URL in your comment above is missing Web

Comment: https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/Templates/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Site%20Pages')/items. This link also throws 403 error.